# how to control frame start and end value using driver and custom properties in blender 2.8

Tags: scripting, drivers

how to control frame start and end value using driver and custom properties in blender 2.8
or using script

'm trying to make multiple animations render with different frame rate .all this to make spacifc frame rate fo each render ..  withe start and end frame change according to some value of my rigg ..

[image]

Comment: You can't control those fields with a driver. As to writing a Python script, it's easy, it's `C.scene.frame_start` or `C.scene.frame_end`. You can set those immediately before calling the `render` operator and it just works.

Answer (score -1):

```
bpy.context.scene or

scene = context.scene
col = layout.column(align=True)
col.prop(scene, "frame_start", text="Frame Start")
col.prop(scene, "frame_end", text="End")
col.prop(scene, "frame_step", text="Step")
```

Comment: I wrote 82 Python answers and I don't understand this code :D Could you present a working, syntactically correct example and explain how it works?